Inconsistent light effect with same distance from the source from the opposite direction
I have the following brdf code to light my scene
float brdf(float specular_color, float diffuse, float ndotv) {
    vec4 c0 = vec4(-1, -.0275, -.572, .022);
    vec4 c1 = vec4(1, .0425, 1.04, -.04);
    vec4 r = diffuse * c0 + c1;
    float a004 = min(r.x * r.x, exp2(-9.28 * ndotv)) * r.x + r.y;
    vec2 AB = vec2(-1.04, 1.04) * a004 + r.zw;
    return specular_color * AB.x + AB.y;
}

float fresnel_term(float specular_color, float vdoth) {
    return specular_color + (1. - specular_color) * pow((1. - vdoth), 5.);
}

float distribution_term(float diffuse, float ndoth) {
    float d = (ndoth * diffuse - ndoth) * ndoth + 1.;
    return diffuse / (d * d * PI);
}

float visibility_term(float diffuse, float ndotv, float ndotl) {
    float gv = ndotl * sqrt(ndotv * (ndotv - ndotv * diffuse) + diffuse);
    float gl = ndotv * sqrt(ndotl * (ndotl - ndotl * diffuse) + diffuse);
    return .5 / max(gv + gl, .00001);
}

void main() {
    vec3 albedo = texture(albedo_texture, uv);
    vec4 pbr_color = texture(pbr_texture, uv);
    float normal_z =
        clamp(sqrt(1. - dot(pbr_color.xy * 2. - 1., pbr_color.xy * 2. - 1.)), normal_z_factor, 1.);
    vec3 normal = normalize(vec3(pbr_color.r, pbr_color.g, normal_z));
    normal.rg -= .5; // Adjust normal to light world space

    vec3 light_direction = normalize(
        vec3(light_location.x - location.x, light_location.y - location.y, light_location.z)
    );

    float ndotl = clamp(dot(normal, light_direction), 0., 1.);
    vec3 view_direction = normalize(vec3(camera_view[2]));
    vec3 half_direction = view_direction + light_direction;
    float vdoth = clamp(dot(view_direction, half_direction), 0., 1.);
    float ndoth = clamp(dot(normal, half_direction), 0., 1.);
    float ndotv = clamp(dot(normal, view_direction), 0., 1.);

    vec3 diffuse = light_color + ndotl;
    vec3 specular = vec3(brdf(SPECULAR, DIFFUSE, ndotv));
    float fresnel = fresnel_term(SPECULAR, vdoth);
    float distribution = distribution_term(DIFFUSE, ndoth);
    float visibility = visibility_term(DIFFUSE, ndotv, ndotl);
    specular += fresnel * (distribution * visibility * PI * ndotl);
    specular *= pow(ndotv + shadow, DIFFUSE) - 1. + shadow;
    specular *= specular_factor;

    vec3 light = diffuse + specular;

    color = light * albedo;
}

The camera has a top down view perspective, and the light_location is the sun.
My scene is at position 0, and the sun rotates around this point keeping always the same same distance from it.
When light_location is vec3(-100, 0, 50) the scene looks good and bright and details from the normals can be seen

But when the location is at the opposite side vec3(100, 0, 50) everything looks dark and the details from the normals are gone

I wonder what might be the issue, if the light is always at the same distance I would suppose that everything should always look equally bright. Is this a bug or is the right behaviour? I'm doing something wrong to calculate the light direction?

I notice your light_direction variable does not factor in the displacement between the object and light on the z axis. What's the reason for that? Your normal calculations also look quite strange - what led you to that particular formula?

Ah thanks! I forgot to factor the displacement in the light direction. The calculation the normal is to avoid having to store the z component in a texture to use that for something else.

I see two errors here.
First, the light direction isn't correctly taking into account the z position of the surface being shaded:
vec3 light_direction = normalize(
    vec3(light_location.x - location.x, light_location.y - location.y, light_location.z)
);

Change that to this: (bonus - less typing!)
vec3 light_direction = normalize(light_location - location);

Next, your normal calculation is a bit confused:
// This isn't a colour, so I'd call it "material properties" or somesuch.
vec4 pbr_color = texture(pbr_texture, uv); 

float normal_z = clamp(
    sqrt(1. - dot(pbr_color.xy * 2. - 1., pbr_color.xy * 2. - 1.)),
    normal_z_factor, 1.
);

// You forgot to decode the rg channels into the -1 to 1 range here.
vec3 normal = normalize(vec3(pbr_color.r, pbr_color.g, normal_z));

// After normalizing is too late.
normal.rg -= .5; // Adjust normal to light world space

Myself, I'd ditch normal_z_factor so we can do this with one square root instead of two:
vec4 mat_props = texture(pbr_texture, uv);
// Since this isn't a colour, I'll refer to it with xy instead of rg.

// Convert from 0 to 1 colour range to -1 to 1 unit vector range once, first. 
vec3 normal = vec3(mat_props.xy * 2. - 1., 0);

normal.z = sqrt(1. - dot(normal.xy, normal.xy));

// No need to normalize in a second step: normal is now a unit vector by construction.


wow thank you! that was the issue!
